# SublimeLinter: How to remove from SublimeText 3

Tags: uninstallation, sublimetext3, sublimelinter

When I tried to remove SublimeLinter on Mac I deleted the package, cache, every part of it in Application Support but it seems I can’t get rid of it in SublimeText 3.

I open ST and I instantly get a message in a new tab from PackageControl telling me that SublimeLinter installed successfully and all the folders and files are created again. Couldn't find any solution online. Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to uninstall it via Package Control. Hit <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>Shift ⇧</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> to open the Command Palette, then type `pcr` and select **`Package Control: Remove Package`**. Scroll down the list, or type `sublimelinter`, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and restart. You should be all set after that.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me guys, I deleted the windows app version of Python because there was two paths when I typed "Where Python" on CMD. Then after I deleted Anaconda and reinstalled it, it fixed itself.